# How to create a Model class having map as one of the variables

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hashmap

I am trying to create a model class for something like this

```
{
    "id": null,
    "name": "TestCompany",
    "domainName": "comany.domain",
    "status": 0,
    "brandAttributes": {
        "contact_person_name": "HS",
        "website_url": "company@gmail.com",
        "address": "Bengaluru",
        "contact_person_email": "hs@gmail.com"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use nested class or 2 class to archive the Model

```
class ModelDTO{
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String domainName;
    private long status;
    private BrandAttributes brandAttributes;
    
    class BrandAttributes{
        private String contact_person_name;
        private String website_url;
        private String address;
        private String contact_person_email;
    }
}
```

or

```
class ModelDTO{
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String domainName;
    private long status;
    private BrandAttributes brandAttributes;
}
    class BrandAttributes{
        private String contact_person_name;
        private String website_url;
        private String address;
        private String contact_person_email;
    }
```

Comment: You should fix the indentation in the second example to make the difference more clear.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a class `Brand` and define attributes of brand object. Then, you can define an attribute `private Brand brand` for company object like this

```
public class Company {
    
    private String id;
    
    private String name;    

    private Brand brand;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There might be two condition of brand attributes.(as its not clear from question)

1. Assuming brand attributes will always have same key means contact_person_name,website_url,address,contact_person_email

if this is the case then  @lokeshwar Solution will work fine.

```
class ModelDTO{
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String domainName;
    private long status;
    private BrandAttributes brandAttributes;
}
    class BrandAttributes{
        private String contact_person_name;
        private String website_url;
        private String address;
        private String contact_person_email;
    }
```

2. But if key is not fixed like some company has this key in brand attributes
   contact_person_name,website_url,address,contact_person_email,**brand_type** here brand_type is extra key and in other company there might be some more different key  then you can use Map where there is no restriction in key.

Model will look like this

```
class ModelDTO{
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String domainName;
    private long status;
    private Map<String,String> brandAttributes;
}
```